# Subscriber in python to std_msgs.msg.Float32 crashes when the maximum float-32bits is sent

Tags: python, c++, publisher, subscribe

Setup:

- a publisher in c++ of std_msgs/msg/Float32 sends the maximum float-32bits (using std::numeric_limits::max())
- a subcriber in c++ to the topic above works just fine
- a subcriber in python to the topic above crashes with the exception below thrown

```
File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 336, in _take_subscription
msg_info = sub.handle.take_message(sub.msg_type, sub.raw)
RuntimeError: Unable to convert call argument to Python object (compile in debug mode for details)
```

Spinning the python-subscriber after the exception is not enough. A new node needs to be constructed and that node can then be "spinned".

Here is an MRE

1. publisher in c++

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/float32.hpp"
#include <limits>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node_ptr(std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("pub"));

    auto pub = node_ptr->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Float32>("number", rclcpp::QoS(10));

    std_msgs::msg::Float32 msg;
    msg.data = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    std::function<void(void)> cb =  [pub, msg](){pub->publish(msg);};
    auto timer = node_ptr->create_wall_timer(std::chrono::seconds(2), cb);

    rclcpp::spin(node_ptr);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

2. A subscriber in python

```
ros2 topic echo number
```

it crashes with "Unable to convert call argument to Python object (compile in debug mode for details)".

3. A subscriber in c++ works just fine.
4. The problem does not exist if the publisher publishes NaN or Inf (instead of the maximum float with 32 bits).

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Please share a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that issue can be replicated quickly.

Comment: @ravi I added an MRE in the post now.